# does strsplit delete some part of data?

Tags: r, split

I have a data frame with 66366 rows when I strsplit one column I get a data frame whit 66347 rows.
this is some part of my data:

```
id        title
3376971   چوب شور آلبينا شيرين عسل
3376989   ويفر رنگارنگ مينو
3376990   کوکي مينو
```

and this is the code I used to split the title:

```
word_df <- data.frame(df,do.call('rbind',strsplit(as.character(df$title),' ',fixed=TRUE)))
```

and I get this: (for the first row)

```
x1  x2     x3      x4 x5
چوب شور آلبينا شيرين عسل
```

how can I split it and have their id too in the new data frame like this for the first row:

```
id        x1  x2     x3      x4 x5
3376971   چوب شور آلبينا شيرين عسل
```

this way at least I will underestand which  id is deleted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we are splitting at the space, and the number of spaces are not the same in each element of 'title', we can pad the split elements with `NA` to make the lengths same and then do the `rbind`

```
lst1 <- strsplit(as.character(df$title),' ',fixed=TRUE)
cbind(df['id'], do.call(rbind, lapply(lst1, `length<-`, max(lengths(lst1)))))
```

---

It would be also possible to use `read.table`

```
cbind(df['id'], read.table(text = as.character(df$title),
       header = FALSE, fill = TRUE))
```

Comment: @arkun, I get this error `Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 66366, 66347`

Comment: @mahnazmohammadi  Can you try with the updated post

Comment: @mahnazmohammadi  I checked with an example data, and it is working fine for me

Comment: @arkun , when I try this `lst1 <- strsplit(as.character(df$title),' ',fixed=TRUE)
cbind(df['id'], do.call(rbind, lapply(lst1, `length<-`, max(lengths(lst1)))))`  as you suggest it doesn't delete my data, thank you so much it really helped me a lot.

Comment: @mahnazmohammadi  Glad to know that it works. I was trying to copy/paste your example, but it is going from right to left